# Python3.3 error loadng a JSON file with multiple entries

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a JSON file named debug.json that I created in Python3.3 that looks  like this:

```
{"TIME": 55.55, "ID":155,"DATA": [17,22,33,44,55]}{"TIME": 56.55, "ID":195,"DATA": [17,22,ff,44,55]}
```

I'm trying to load it with the following code:

```
import json
with open("debug.json",'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    testing = json.loads(f.read())
```

However when I try this I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Extra data line 1 column 92
```

This is where the second JSON object starts in the text  file...I'm guessing that I am missing something pretty trivial  here but I haven't found any examples that relate to my problem. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I know this question is quite old, but FYI for anyone else who stumbles across it: The real issue here is that a JSON document - which is what python's json parser knows how to read - is composed of exactly one JSON value, which can be an object, array, string, number, boolean, or null. The contents of "debug.json" is not a valid JSON document; it's multiple JSON objects in a row. That's why it needs to be read piecemeal with raw_decode().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode), which accepts JSON with extra data at the end, such as another JSON object, and returns a tuple with the first object decoded and the position of the next object.

Example with your JSON :

```
import json

js = """{"TIME": 55.55, "ID":155,"DATA": [17,22,33,44,55]}{"TIME": 56.55, "ID":195,"DATA": [17,22,ff,44,55]}"""

json.JSONDecoder().raw_decode(js) # ({'TIME': 55.55, 'DATA': [17, 22, 33, 44, 55], 'ID': 155}, 50)

js[50:] # '{"TIME": 56.55, "ID":195,"DATA": [17,22,ff,44,55]}'
```

As you can see, it successfully decoded the first object and told us where the next object starts (in this case at the 50th character).

Here is a function that I made that can decode multiple JSON objects and returns a list with all of them :

```
def multipleJSONDecode(js):
    result = []
    while js:
        obj, pos = json.JSONDecoder().raw_decode(js)
        result.append(obj)
        js = js[pos:]
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the file, make sure that you have at most one valid JSON string *per line*.  Then, when you need to read them back out, you can loop over the lines in the file one at a time:

```
import json
testing = []
with open("debug.json",'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        testing.append(json.loads(line))
```